# Why is hook undefined when using BackHandler?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I've run into an issue where my state isn't up to date when using BackHandler. The state is actually up to date but when pressing the back button it isn't (I've checked by logging the value of the state using an onPress). setData is an async function setting data to all the hooks upon initial rendering. Pressing back would log nothing while logging listNameInput from a button onPress would log the correct value.

Example code below:

```
export default function ListScreen({ route, navigation }) {
    const [listNameInput, setListNameInput] = useState('');

    function handleBackButtonClick(){
        console.log(listNameInput);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setData();
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButtonClick);
        return () => {
            BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButtonClick)
        };}, []);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you include `setData` ? ... you're likely pressing back-button before the async-op has finished its job